# Function title var

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables, var

I have written a code that finds two strings and in return it should tell me if these two strings are existing:

```
 function searchTwoString(data, str1, str2) {

   var strX = str1 + " " + strValueX + "\r\n";
   var strY = str2 + " " + strValueY;
   var strValueX;
   var strValueY;

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if (data[i] === str1) {
       var strValueX = " exist";
       continue;

     } else if (data[i] === str2) {
       var strValueY = " exist";
       break;
     } 
   }

   return strX + strY;

 }
```

**Achieved result:**

> str1 undefined
>
> str2 undefined

**Expected result:**

> str1 exist
>
> str2 exist

it tells me my `strvalueX` & `strvalueY` are `undefined` isn't it i have already gave the values in the if statement?

thanks to those who will help out

Comment: Move `var strX = str1 + " " + strValueX + "\r\n";` and `var strY = str2 + " " + strValueY;` to after the `for` loop, just before the `return`, and remove the second `var` inside the loops. Also, not directly related to your question, your loop doesn't seem to be correct...

Comment: You are declaring `strValueX` and `strValueY` twice. You don't need the `var` in the for loop.

Comment: because you defined `strX` and `strY` at the top, but at that time `strValueX` is undefined

Comment: What happens if `str2` appears before `str1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question with comment.

Hope you understand what I'm talking about.

```
function searchTwoString(data, str1, str2) {

   var strX;// = str1 + " " + strValueX + "\r\n";
   var strY;// = str2 + " " + strValueY;
   var strValueX;
   var strValueY;

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       if (data[i] === str1) {
           // var strValueX = " exist";
           // do not define again
           strValueX = " exist";
           continue;

       } else if (data[i] === str2) {
           // var strValueY = " exist";
           // do not define again
           strValueY = " exist";
           break;
       }
   }
   // define the value here after strValueX and strValueY is set
   strX = str1 + " " + strValueX + "\r\n";
   strY = str2 + " " + strValueY;

   return strX + strY;
```

}

Comment: this is what i'm been trying to do the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your statements is off.  In lines 2 and 3, you are using `strValueX` and `strValueY` before they are defined.  Lines 2 and 3 should be moved to before the return so that they will have the updated values.

I believe there is also a shadowing problem, as in the if statements you are creating new variables with the `var` keyword (e.g. `var strValueX = " exist";`).  You will want to remove `var` from the if statements so that it updates the values of the outer variables.